# What is the best way to showcase my StackExchange activity on LinkedIn?

Tags: support, external-project

I have seen specific questions about the flair/groups. But how could I showcase my SE reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've been able to include it in any way is under "Websites"

[image]

Then in my summary, I encourage people to check it out if they'd like to see a showcase of my code. I guess you could also include it in "projects," but it doesn't really seem to fit there.

Comment: How'd you get the upside down name?  Are those just funky unicode upside down characters, or were you able to execute some sort of CSS transform?

Comment: @AdamRackis: Just funky upside down unicode characters. I wish it was some awesome CSS hack though